# How do I programmatically fix local menus to be shown only for a content type?

Tags: 8, navigation

I am using the following lines in a links.task.yml file.

```
x.nodename_updates:
  route_name: view.great_view_name1.page_1
  base_route: entity.node.canonical
  title: 'Updates'
  weight: 50

x.nodename_subscriptions:
  route_name: view.great_view_name2.page_1
  base_route: entity.node.canonical
  title: 'Subscriptions'
  weight: 50
```

The submenus are shown on all nodes. I would like to show them for a single content type, but when I use the entity name in the base_route such as entity.TYPE.canonical, it doesn't work. It works for other entities that are defined in classes with annotations.

I know it is possible to fix it through `hook_menu_local_task_alter()`, but this is something I believe can be fixed within the links.task.yml file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to do that entirely within *links.task.yml*.

If you see [the documentation](https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/menu-api/providing-module-defined-local-tasks), you'll see that the only possible keys are:

> `route_name`: The machine name of the local task route - this also
> determines where it's displayed.
>
> `title`: The title of the local action. By default, it will be passed through t() and localized. Strings with spaces should use single quotes.
>
> `title_context` (optional): context for t()
>
> `base_route`: The route where the "root" tab (generally the top,
> leftmost one) is displayed and which serves to group a set of tabs.
>
> `parent_id` (optional): The plugin ID of the tab that is the parent -
> only relevant for 2nd level tabs. If this is set, base_route should be
> omitted and will be supplied from the parent
>
> `weight`: (optional) The
> integer weight (lower weight tabs are further left, default is 0).

None of these keys will help you with what you're trying to do.

Your options are to use [hook_menu_local_task_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Menu%21menu.api.php/function/hook_menu_local_tasks_alter/8.2.x), as you've noted, or create a deriver class to [Dynamically Generate Local Tasks](https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/menu-api/providing-module-defined-local-tasks#dynamic-local-task-generation).

From that same documentation page, your yaml would look something like:

```
example.local_tasks:
  deriver: 'Drupal\example\Plugin\Derivative\DynamicLocalTasks'
  weight: 100
```

And a deriver class something like:

```
namespace Drupal\example\Plugin\Derivative;

use Drupal\Component\Plugin\Derivative\DeriverBase;

/**
 * Defines dynamic local tasks.
 */
class DynamicLocalTasks extends DeriverBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getDerivativeDefinitions($base_plugin_definition) {
    // Implement dynamic logic to provide values for the same keys as in example.links.task.yml.

    // Here you would check for your node canonical route and node bundle
    // to generate the task definition only if appropriate.
    $this->derivatives['example.task_id'] = $base_plugin_definition;
    $this->derivatives['example.task_id']['title'] = "I'm a tab";
    $this->derivatives['example.task_id']['route_name'] = 'example.route';
    
    return parent::getDerivativeDefinitions($base_plugin_definition);
  }

}
```

Comment: In the case asked by the OP, there aren't properties that can be changed only for a bundle. For example, the base route is the same for all the nodes (*entity.node.canonical*).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed and speedy response!

Answer (score 1):

I don't konw if there's a better way to do it now but few years ago I did it using a custom access: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36496998/drupal-8-how-to-add-task-and-contextual-links-for-specific-node-type/36636263#36636263

In my case it was easier because I was creating the routes in my module.

Since your routes are created by views you would need to implement a RouteSubscriber to alter the route, add the `_custom_access` and `_node_types` requirements.

**/!\ Warning:** I am not sure since I never tried it on views routes but it might conflicts or breaks the rules you've set from the views UI to access this view. It should be compatible with a `_permission` rule, maybe not with an `_entity_access` rule.

**yourmodule/yourmodule.services.yml**

```
services:
  yourmodule.route_subscriber:
    class: Drupal\yourmodule\Routing\RouteSubscriber
    tags:
    - { name: event_subscriber }
```

**yourmodule/src/Routing/RouteSubscriber.php**

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\yourmodule\Routing;

use Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteSubscriberBase;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection;

/**
 * Listens to the dynamic route events.
 */
class RouteSubscriber extends RouteSubscriberBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function alterRoutes(RouteCollection $collection) {
    if ($route = $collection->get('view.great_view_name1.page_1')) {
      $requirements = $route->getRequirements();
      $requirements['_custom_access'] = '\Drupal\yourmodule\Access\ByNodeTypeAccessCheck::access';
      // Replace 'my_node_type' with the name of the node type you want.
      // Since it's an array, you can add more than one node type.
      $requirements['_node_types'] = ['my_node_type'];
      $requirements['node'] = '\d+';
      $route->setRequirements($requirements);
      
      $options = $route->getOptions();
      $options['parameters'] = $options['parameters'] ?? [];
      $options['parameters']['node'] = [
        'type' => [
          'entity:node',
        ],
      ];
      $route->setOptions($options);
    }
  }

}
```

**yourmdule/src/Access/ByNodeTypeAccessCheck.php**

```
namespace Drupal\yourmdule\Access;

use Drupal\Core\Access\AccessCheckInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Access\AccessResult;
use Drupal\node\NodeInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Route;

/**
 * Check the access to a node task based on the node type.
 */
class ByNodeTypeAccessCheck implements AccessCheckInterface {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function applies(Route $route) {
    return NULL;
  }

  /**
   * A custom access check.
   *
   * @param \Drupal\node\NodeInterface $node
   *   Run access checks for this node.
   */
  public function access(Route $route, NodeInterface $node) {
    if ($route->hasRequirement('_node_types')) {
      $allowed_node_types = $route->getRequirement('_node_types');
      if (in_array($node->getType(), $allowed_node_types)) {
        return AccessResult::allowed();
      }
    }
    return AccessResult::forbidden();
  }

}
```